# Ruby gem with more classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I would like to create a gem in ruby, which to contain more classes, not just the one with the same name as the gem's name, and to call the methods of these classes as it is described below.

I would like to have the following tree:

```
my_handlers
-lib
--my_first_handler.rb
--my_second_handler.rb
```

After creating and installing the gem, I would like to call the methods of the classes like

```
MyHandlers::MyFirstHandler.Method1
MyHandlers::MySecondHandler.Method1
```

Is it possible to create a gem like this?
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main namespace for a gem with same name shell be not a class, but module, and all classes, and other modules shell be nested into it. For your case it will look like:

**lib/my_handlers.rb:**

```
require 'my_handlers/my_first_handler'
require 'my_handlers/my_second_handler'
```

**lib/my_handlers/version.rb:**

```
module MyHandlers
   Version = 0.0.1
end
```

**lib/my_handlers/my_first_handler.rb:**

```
module MyHandlers
   module MyFirstHandler
      def method
      end
   end
end
```

**lib/my_handlers/my_second_handler.rb:**

```
module MyHandlers
   module MySecondHandler
      def method
      end
   end
end
```

and organize an access to the methods as follows:

```
MyHandlers::Version # => 0.0.1
MyHandlers::MyFirstHandler.method
MyHandlers::MySecondHandler.method
```

or using `::include` operation to include the module's methods into a class as its instance methods:

```
class A
   include MyHandlers::MyFirstHandler
end

A.new.method
```

or using `::extend` operation to extend a class with the module's methods as the classe's singleton methods:

```
class A
   extend MyHandlers::MyFirstHandler
end

A.method
```

Comment: Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.


packet_handler.rb:
`module PacketHandler
end`

xml_handler.rb:
`module PacketHandler
  module XmlHandler
    method1
    end
  end
end`

After building and installing, when calling
`PacketHandler::XmlHandler.method1`
it tells me: uninitialized constant PacketHandler::XmlHandler (NameError)

Comment: @ChocapicSz please update your post, but i guess that you haven't incluede the **xml_handler.rb**

Comment: It works now. The problem was that the tree I made it was wrong but now it is ok. Thank you very much! :)